# How to install g++ on Conda under Linux?

Tags: g++, conda, miniconda

I have tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge gcc
```

but it only installed `gcc`. I also need `g++`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### Narrow Solution

It ships under the package name `gxx`:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge gxx
```

### Recommended Specification

Generally, I prefer using the Conda Forge `compilers` package or one of its subpackages (e.g., `cxx-compiler`), as this specification works across platforms. For example, `cxx-compiler` will install g++ on Linux, clang++ on OSX, and vc on Windows:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge cxx-compiler
```

Comment: `cxx-compiler` works for me

Comment: you are saying to do `conda install -c conda-forge cxx-compiler` ?

Comment: @sAguinaga yes.

Comment: I also didn't know about cxx-compiler and it's very nice, thanks! However, it apparently doesn't play well with system libraries? I have installed SDL2 dependencies via apt and it works 100% with the system g++, but conda's g++ can't find them. I proceeded to install them via conda itself and they start to work one by one, but not all are available. So when I try to add the system ones that are left (like ibus) via C_INCLUDE_PATH, I start to get all sorts of other very weird and apparently unrelated errors instead. I'm kinda stuck ;/
Does any of you have any idea?

Comment: @GabrielGalli that is substantial enough a question to merit a proper question.